# An example for using the strong law of large numbers

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, convergence, law-of-large-numbers

> Let $X_i$'s be independent random variables such that $X_i$'s are symmetric about 0 and $\mathrm{Var}(X_i) = 2i - 1$, for $i \ge 1$. Then,
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_n > n \log n)$$
>
> 1. does not exist.
> 2. equals $\frac12$.
> 3. equals 1.
> 4. equals 0.

Attempt:

(I tried to use Strong-LLN but couldn't figure it out.)

Taking $ b_n = n \log(n)$ and letting $ S_n = \sum X_i$, if the series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac {2i-1}{(ilog(i))^2}  $ converges then SLLN will hold for $X_n$, i.e., then $ \frac {S_n}{n \log(n)} $ converges almost surely to $0$. Then option 4 must be correct?

Comment: Since this is a multiple choice question it indicates that the self-study tag is probably needed.  Shouldn't the question be for all i >=1.

Comment: Your series does not converge, try plugging in $i=1$.

Comment: @JohnK Hint: $\operatorname{Var}(X_1+\cdots+X_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n(2i-1)=n^2$.  Now consider what Chebyshev's Inequality tells us about the chance that $X_1+\cdots + X_n$ exceeds $n\log(n)$.  That gives an upper bound for the sequence in question--and, I believe, makes its convergence quite clear.

Comment: @whuber I was referring to the claim of the OP that the series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac {2i-1}{log(i)}$ converges. I am sorry if that was not clear. Of course you are right, the probability limit of the event is zero.

Comment: but to apply Chebyshev's Inequality the given terms sholud be in modulos,  how would that be applied here ?

Comment: Hint: for any real number $x$, $x\leq |x|$.

Comment: i din get it please can you solve this one